# GeoServer converting PostGIS timestamp with time zone

Tags: postgis, geoserver

In a PostGIS view i have a field of data type "timestamp with time zone". In GeoServer this field is show with datatype "Timestamp" 
[image]

My problem is that i want the Timestamp to be show in my application exactly as it is in my Database as **UTM. +00**.

What i get back from GeoServer via WFS request is:

> 2010-08-20T16:56:15.095-04:00

What is stored in the PostGIS database is:

> 2010-08-20 20:56:15.095+00

**How do i tell GeoServer not to convert the time so that i see the time exactly how it is in the database as UTM? Is it on Apache, System Time, GeoServer config?**

Running GeoServer on latest stable Suse linux Ent.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only way I can think of is to change the default timezone on your server so that it is UTM+00. When the postgres jdbc driver gets the date from the server it will parse it into a Date object, which will by default display it in the default timezone. And there is no way with GeoServer wfs to supply a custom format for date output in GML.

You can try setting the timezone with the jvm system property: -Duser.timezone=GMT.