# GeoServer timestamp format

Tags: geoserver, time

In my app, I use GeoServer to serve my features and OpenLayers as a client. My data contains dates info in this format: `'yyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss'` but when it comes from GeoServer, it appears like: `2013-01-08T06:17:37+03:00` !!

How can I change its format?

Comment: try to read this answer http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/12399/3071 and [Time Support in Geoserver WMS](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wms/time.html)

Comment: So there is no way to re-format it ?!

Comment: AFAIK, unfortunately no way other than i have mentioned.

Comment: You can do anything you like in your client - that is an ISO date coming in most languages can read it and provide tools to format datetimes as you need.