# Image Mosaic Time Dimension Refresh

Tags: postgis, geoserver, image-mosaic

I have a temporal Image Mosaic layer containing 15 daily geotiffs. I want to add the 16th day and have Geoserver expose it dynamically. I attempted this by

1. adding the new geotiff - rtmatmax_20150116.tif to my image mosaic directory
2. adding a new row to the postgis table geoserver had generated:

> fid-|-the_geom-|-location---------------------|-ingestion
>
> 16   |    01030......    |    rtmatmax_20150116.tif  |  2015-01-16
>   17:00:00.000000

But when I try to view the new day in the openlayers preview nothing appears.What am I missing?

Comment: There is no caching in GeoServer as far as time dimensions are concerned. There is only caching of BBOX hence unless your geotiff is outside the cache BBOX this procedure should work.

It is best to use the REST Interface though for this kind of tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Autorefreshing does actually work with the method used in the question. This ended up being a date issue.

After examining the Postgis table geoserver generated, I realized the ingestion date column was the **day before** the raster date in all the autogenerated rows. So I changed the row I manually add from:

```
fid-|-the_geom-|-location---------------------|-ingestion

16 | 01030...... | rtmatmax_20150116.tif | 2015-01-16 17:00:00.000000
```

to be this instead:

```
fid-|-the_geom-|-location---------------------|-ingestion

16 | 01030...... | rtmatmax_20150116.tif | 2015-01-15 17:00:00.000000
```

When I make a request using &time=2015-01-16 and tail the geoserver log, I see it is interpreted as:

```
Time = [[Thu Jan 15 17:00:00 MST 2015, Fri Jan 16 16:59:59 MST 2015]]
```

Comment: Looking back this all could have been avoided by [setting geoserver's timezone to GMT](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/12399/geoserver-converting-postgis-timestamp-with-time-zone)